# /boot full, how do I delete the files kernel there safely with no complicated scripts?

Tags: boot

I just update, but, I don't want to restart the computer, 'cause it may not reboot

Comment: @saiarcot895 thanks for the reference, but for my current level it looks _too automatic_  'cause I want to leave the new kernel and two versions behind just for backup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get your current kernel image

```
uname -r
```

Then find out what other kernels version you have installed (and not using usually)

```
sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*'
```

Now time to remove all the other kernel using the following command

```
sudo apt-get remove
```

Don't remove the kernel image that was shown on the first command (its the one you are using).

Finally

```
cross your fingers
```

Comment: Thanks, I made this mini script to list the installed kernels, and then use `sudo apt-get remove` to uninstall the older ones.

**dpkg --list 'linux-image*' | grep ^ii | grep -v linux-image-generic | grep -v `uname -r`**

Answer (score 1):

Test this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i

OLDCONF=$(dpkg -l|grep "^rc"|awk '{print $2}')

CURKERNEL=$(uname -r|sed 's/-*[a-z]//g'|sed 's/-386//g')

LINUXPKG="linux-(image|headers|ubuntu-modules|restricted-modules)"

METALINUXPKG="linux-(image|headers|restricted-modules)-(generic|i386|server|common|rt|xen)"

OLDKERNELS=$(dpkg -l|awk '{print $2}'|grep -E $LINUXPKG |grep -vE $METALINUXPKG|grep -v $CURKERNEL)

apt-get purge $OLDCONF

apt-get purge $OLDKERNELS

apt-get autoremove

apt-get clean
```